# why pusher works on localhost but not on a live website

Tags: php, yii, publish, pusher

I've used **Pusher API** to put a simple push notification in place. I've tested everything and Pusher works on my `localhost`. When I put the same code on a live website, Pusher doesn't publish my message. That's interesting to note that if I push from localhost I can see the message on the live version.

It seems that I have no problem subscribing to a channel, but the problem is that I cannot publish a message on the channel.

This is my code:

```
// Create pusher event
$pusher=Yii::app()->pusher;
$data = array('message'=>"myMessageContent");
$pusher->trigger('test_channel','my_event',$data);
```

Is there something that I'm unaware of?

**EDIT 1:**

This is the output I've got from debugging:

```
string(112) "Timestamp expired: Given timestamp (2014-08-15T17:40:26Z) not within 600s of server time (2014-08-15T09:10:29Z) "
```

My server time is exactly the same as my localhost (13:44), but here I see something different?! 17:40?

Comment: How did you check the time on your server is the same as localhost? Looks like it is not.

Comment: @putvande, with date on terminal.

Answer (score 3):

server's clock was drifted considerably so I used `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` on terminal and corrected the time. To prevent future problems I put that in the crontab.

Phew...